# Enumerate permissions that are declared in AndroidManifest

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest

Is it possible in runtime to enumerate permissions that are declared in AndroidManifest ?

Update:
Declared in this way:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Comment: The Android Manifest file is an XML file.  You can walk it just like you would any other XML file.

Comment: What does "enumerate" mean here?

Comment: @TheWanderer Just to get list of declared permissions

Comment: Declared, like `<permission android:name="com.my.custom.PERMISSION">` or declared like `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA">`?

Comment: I updated question

Comment: try this :https://stackoverflow.com/a/3392628/10738439

Answer (score 0):

You may ask the all required runtime permissions on the start of your app. You must array of permission check. If it returns false means you must ask permissions as array and in the method **onRequestPermissionsResult** method you can check if the permission is granted or not. If the permission is not granted check the permission once again. Thanks in advance